# Need two columns of posts in WordPress with bootstrap.

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a intranet site for a client and it works like a Facebook/twitter type feed. However the page is split into three columns using bootstraps grid.

One column is a sidebar for navagation, but the other two should be populated with posts in the following order.

```
1  2
3  4
5  6

Show more...
```

I'm struggling with geting the wordpress posts to span over bother the columns.

I'm currenlty putting each post in a  but this just stacks all of the divs and I get a large space between posts which are bigger.

Here is how the content is currently displaying.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FjJv.png

This is how I would like it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDoXX.png

Many Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could either have a look at `CSS3` columns, with CSS3 columns I don't think you'll be able to get the order you want though - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/ .Or using a `Javascript` solution, something like `Masonry` - http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: You have to show us code, otherwise we can't help.  Your desired outcome is actually not simple to achieve, it will require some php work (not just html / css), or else some sort of javascript solution (not the best way to go).

Comment: Nick, thanks for the suggestion, I've never tried CSS3 cols before but will have a play about with it! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looping through your posts twice, rendering the first column in the first pass and the second column in the second pass. The first time discard even-numbered posts, the second time discard odd-numbered posts. Then you can build up a column at a time, rather than a row at a time and structure the HTML like -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php // loop through posts discarding evens ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php // loop through posts discarding odds ?>
    </div>
</div>
```